# Using python string in sqlite3 LIKE query

Tags: python, sqlite, cgi

thanks for any help in advance. I have seen several solutions to this problem on Stackoverflow and Google, but none seem to work for me when implemented. I am simply trying to pass in a python string contained inside a variable to a sqlite3 WHERE LIKE query. Not getting any errors, just no screen output. Here are the codes I've tried:

Try 1:
    import cgi
    import sqlite3

```
#Get string/Clean string:
form = cgi.FieldStorage() 
term = form.getfirst('term', 'empty')
term = cgi.escape(term)

#Open DB Connection:
conn = sqlite3.connect("mydatabase.db")
cursor = conn.cursor()

#Search and Print Results
print "\nResults from a LIKE query on %s:\n" % term
sql='SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE column LIKE %s'
args=['%'+term+'%']
cursor.execute(sql,args)
print cursor.fetchall()
```

Try2:
    import cgi
    import sqlite3

```
#Get string/Clean string:
form = cgi.FieldStorage() 
term = form.getfirst('term', 'empty')
term = cgi.escape(term)

#Open DB Connection:
conn = sqlite3.connect("mydatabase.db")
cursor = conn.cursor()

#Search and Print Results
print "\nResults from a LIKE query on %s:\n" % term
term = '%' + term + '%'
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE ?", (term,) )
print cursor.fetchall()
```

The code works if I put LIKE '%http%', but always fails with the variable. Does the cgi have something to do with it? If I simply print term to the screen it prints fine.

Comment: Does it work if you add quotes around your placeholder string? For example, in Try 1: `sql='SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE column LIKE "%s"'`?

Comment: No, that is still failing to print.

Comment: Your second code block should work (if you remove the `cgi.escape`; SQL is not HTTP, and SQL parameters do not need escaping). What exactly is the term output by the `print`?

Comment: Thank you so much, this finally works and good to know about SQL escaping. 'term' is a string variable taken from text input on the html page.

Comment: Just realized, the variable 'term' IS coming from HTTP page, so I would need to escape it, or?